# Got a bunch of images, need to put them together to form a big picture (like a puzzle)

Tags: php

I got a bunch of images (225 in total). Example of their names:

```
4n27e.png
4n28e.png
4n29e.png
4n30e.png
5n12e.png
5n25e.png
5n26e.png
5n27e.png
5n28e.png
```

I need to form one big picture out of all these images. For example first line of images would be 4n27e (2nd image 4n28e, 3rd image 4n29e and so on). Second line of images would start from 5n12e (2nd image 5n25e and so on). What methods do i need to search for to solve this?

Note: i need to do this only with php and maybe some javascript.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: 1 savable image? or laid out together using html?

Comment: Laid out togehter using html

Comment: @Ares i dont really know what to look for, never did anything similar to this. I saw a bunch of other methods that solve this exact problem but they all use other programing languages and i need it in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test case for logic, you can replace the `echo` with an `img` tag, and /or use `div`.

```
<?php
$images=array();
$images[]="4n27e.png";
$images[]="4n28e.png";
$images[]="4n29e.png";
$images[]="4n30e.png";
$images[]="5n12e.png";
$images[]="5n25e.png";
$images[]="5n26e.png";
$images[]="5n27e.png";
$images[]="5n28e.png";

echo "<table border='1'>";
$oldIndex=0;
$row=1;
foreach($images as $image)
{
    if(substr($image,0,1)!=$oldIndex)
    {
    if($row>1){echo "</tr>";}

    echo "<tr>";
    $oldIndex=substr($image,0,1);
    $row++;
    }
    echo "<td>$image</td>";

}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Hanky perhaps you could use glob("*.png") to load in the images from a folder ? Also missing a closing tr by any chance ?

Comment: Yep I agree we could, but that's for the OP to build upon :) And yea I'll fix the closing `tr` now. Thanks for your message!